# Drag and drop in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery

I need to create a new application in which the UI designer decided to heavily use drag and drop. Some of the drag and drop functionality would be:

1. Moving items within a list
2. Moving items to a trash can to delete them
3. Possibly letting users have a "My Page" where users would use widgets to create a personalized page

As soon as the user drags and drops something, I need a way to persist it to the database (ie., there is no "save" button)

This needs to be an inhouse application built from scratch (no MS webparts or 3 party components)

I understand JQuery supports drag and drop on the client side. My initial thought is that there needs to be heavy use of AJAX. Can some one help me join the dots and suggest an architecture using .NET that would be scalable and solid?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're interested in the [.serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Sortable#method-serialize) method of the [jQueryUI Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Sortable).

> **Serialize:**
>   "Serializes the sortable's item id's into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server."
>
> [continue reading...](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Sortable#method-serialize)